# How can I reference an external stylesheet inside Visual Studio generated documentation?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, documentation

I'm currently developing a project in C# using Visual Studio 2022. Inside of my source code, I have written XML summaries for my classes and functions.
Visual Studio then uses those comments to generate an XML documentation file for the whole project.

My problem is that the generated file is raw XML, and not very nice to look at.

I have tried adding a XSL stylesheet manually to the XML file, but it's rewritten at every compilation of the project, plus this solution is not very practical.

I have also tried adding this line inside of my `.csproj` file :

`<DocumentationTransform>path/to/documentation-style.xsl</DocumentationTransform>`
...but the reference does not appear in the XML, so it's still "raw".

Is there a way to automatically link an XSL stylesheet to Visual Studio's documentation ?

Comment: Have a look at the [Pretty Doc Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlivierJacot-Descombes.PrettyDocComments) Visual Studio Extension. It does not create a documentation but displays the XML doc comments in a nice way inside the Visual Studio Editor.

Comment: Thanks ! Not really what I was looking for but that's a great tool, it does look way nicer !

Comment: You may find [Sandcastle Help File Builder](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) useful. You need to create a SHFB project file and tell it where the assemblies you want documenting are, but when you build that project, it can create a rather nice looking help file or documentation web site for you.

Comment: Visual Studio uses settings from the configuration file during the documentation generation process. You can specify the location of your XSL stylesheet in this file.